# Error al subir aplicacción FasApi (python) a Cloud run

Tags: docker, fastapi, despliegue

Hola estoy intentando subir un proyecto a Cloud run de google, en concreto un aplicacion hecha en fast api usando docker, pero me da este error:

```
Revision 'fastapi-fastgallery-00002-fdk' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8000 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: Abre Cloud Logging  For more troubleshooting guidance, see
```

Entiendo que es un fallo del que el `puerto 8000`, pero no sé cómo puedo arreglarlo:

Este es el enlace al repositorio docker:

https://hub.docker.com/layers/victor039/fastapi-fastgallery/1.0.0/images/sha256-9797ec1cbd4b8cbf2aa12344452966f45852be86d399f1f14766b1959c203f09?context=repo

En local me funciona, si necesitáis algún otro dato que no he compartido por favor pedirlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Links relacionados: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting?hl=es-419#container-failed-to-start + https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662223/3613462